# ASP.NET MVC Cache is clearing itself

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 application which is running on a Windows 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5 machine. There is a wierd behavior which I cannot figure it out. The cache seems is clearing itself. By cache, I mean `MemoryCache.Default`, `HttpContext.Current.Cache`, and also `OutputCache`. I'm googling the issue for hours and seems nothing is wrong. Can you list cause of clearing cache? I mean is there a checklist which I can test the server against it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you delete a file under your IIS folder? Deleting a file under IIS folder causes the IIS to restart

Comment: When does the cache clear itself? Always after the same amount of time?

Comment: @KhanhTO, Messing with the application folder would only cause the *application* to restart, not for a full IIS restart.

Comment: @Javad_Amiry, You need a configure a distributed cache

Comment: @haim770: That's what I meant, sorry about using the wrong word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those caches are held in memory, and as such are volatile.  They are held against the W3wp process that IIS spawns to handle those requests.

After a period of inactivity, IIS closes down the processes, so these caches will be cleared.

IIS also closes down the processes (recycles the app pool)

- By default after 1746 mins (IIRC)
- After the memory used by a thread reaches a set threshold
- Caches are also isolated by thread, so if you have a web farm/web garden, these caches are not shared, again IIRC

If you need to persist these items longer, then you will need to look at caching the objects in a persisted storage area, such as a db or application state managed server.

Comment: I do have a web garden :) Thanks a lot.